# How do I conditionally apply a custom validator to a form field?

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-directive

I have a re-usable directive where the use of a custom validator is optional.

What's a good way to apply this validator attribute conditionally?

```
<input type="text"
       name="{{name}}"
       require-items="{{requireitems}}"
       mongoose-error>
```

The `require-items` is an optional validation I want to pass to my directive.

The directive would be called like this:

```
//with validator enabled
<my-directive requireitems="{{items.length}}"></my-directive>

//no validator
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

Comment: Share your directive code

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `my-directive` directive `link` function:

```
 link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
        if(iAttrs.requireItems) { 
             // checks if require-items is present
             // process your validation here
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check how it's done in `ng-required`, using attributes and observing the same to have dynamic changes also handled.

```
var requiredDirective = function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
      if (!ctrl) return;
      attr.required = true; // force truthy in case we are on non input element

      ctrl.$validators.required = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        return !attr.required || !ctrl.$isEmpty(viewValue);
      };

      attr.$observe('required', function() {
        ctrl.$validate();
      });
    }
  };
};
```

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/validators.js#L61)